# How to access hasMany in another hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel

How do i access another hasMany in eloquent? There are 3 models: post,comment and upvote. Each post hasMany comment and each comment hasMany upvote.

If I delete the post, i want to delete the comment as well as the comment's upvote.

```
$post = Post::find ($id);
$post->comment->each->delete() // deletes all the post comment
$post->delete() //delete the post
```

This works, but how do i delete the comment's upvote ?

```
$post->comment->upvote->each->delete() // does not work to delete comment's upvote
```

This does not work. It returns 
*message: "Property [upvote] does not exist on this collection instance."*

**UPDATE**

Below are the table schemes

**Post**

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->string('title');
$table->string('desc');
$table->string('category');
$table->integer('total_comment')->default(0);
$table->timestamps();
});
```

**Comment**

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->foreign('post_id')->references("id")->on("posts")->onDelete("cascade");
$table->string('comment');
$table->integer('upvote')->default(0);
$table->timestamps();
});
```

**Upvote**

```
Schema::create('upvote', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->integer('comment_id')->unsigned()->foreign('comment_id')->references("id")->on("comments")->onDelete("cascade");
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Its better to add `onDelete('cascade') in model migration

Answer (score 1):

If your Models are connected by a *Foreign Key* Constraints,
 **all** `post` with its related `comments` & **all** `comments` with its related `votes` will be deleted, **but** you must include `->onDelete('cascade');` in the tables migration:

Comment table migration

```
$table->foreign('post_id')
  ->references('id')->on('posts')
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Votes table migration

```
$table->foreign('comment_id')
  ->references('id')->on('comments')
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

**Edit:**

Another way you can do this is to get the `comments` of the `post` then iterate each `comment` to delete its `upvotes`:

```
//Get the requierd post
$post = Post::find ($id);

//Iterate the requierd post comments
foreach ($post->comment as comment){
 //delete each comment upvotes
 comment->each->upvote->delete()
}

//then delete the comments
$post->comment->each->delete() // deletes all the post comment
```

Comment: I already adjusted the tables to you suggestion but when i did $post->delete();  only the post is deleted, the comment and upvote is still there

Comment: Did you run `php artisan migrate` after adjusting the table structures?

Comment: yes. Try checking my schemes, i already updated the post above

Comment: Try to define it like `$table->foreign('post_id')
  ->references('id')->on('posts')
  ->onDelete('cascade');`, if its still not working you can see my edited answer to try another way.

Comment: I had to adjust it manually in mysql to get the relationship cause the schema wasnt building it ,, so there was no foreign key being made,, now it works,, thanks